# How to make code sleep without using modules

Tags: python, time, sleep, micropython

I'm currently in a bit of a predicament, I'm trying to make a micro python program that has a small time delay for readability, but cannot use any imports. I would simply install the module onto the machine I'm working on, but the program is designed for the Casio-FX9860GIII Calculator.

My first thought was to use a long calculation that takes the calculator a while to process, hence making the program "sleep" for a short period of time, but I've had no success with that. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `datetime` is in the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/). So this isn't available either? How long shall the sleep be? you can do the calculations many times in a loop...

Comment: im trying this at the minute, just trying to tweak it to get the time to be equal to the second, code looks like this: class systemGenerics():

    def systemSleep(depth):
        i = 0
        for i in range(0, depth*50000000):
            3 * 3
            3 * 3
            3 * 3

Answer (score 1):

managed to figure it out, just used a for loop and did some testing using the Time function to get the timings right for my system, code looks like this

```
def systemSleep(s):
        i = 0
        for i in range(0, s*45100000):
            3 * 3
            3 * 3
            3 * 3
```

Comment: Of course that's not really "sleeping" because it's going to thrash your CPU

Comment: it does everything i need it to do, if you have any other solution im all ears